# Undefined Variables Error - PHP

Tags: php

I'm declaring this two but I always get error. 
I'm thinking of isset but I don't know how to use it. It's been my 3 weeks self-studying PHP and i'm not really good yet.

```
 $searchq = $_POST['lname'];
 $searchw = $_POST['fname'];
```

This are my errors:

```
Undefined variable: searchq 
Undefined variable: searchw
```

I will appreciate any help.

```
$per_page = 20;

                $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(fname) FROM sheet1");
                $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

                $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
                $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

                if( (isset($_POST['fname'])) && (isset($_POST['lname'])) ){
                    ($searchq = $_POST['lname']);
                    ($searchw = $_POST['fname']);

                }
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sheet1 WHERE lname like '%$searchq%' AND fname like '%$searchw%' LIMIT $start, $per_page");
                    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        echo '<p>', $query_row['fname'] . ' ' . $query_row['lname'] ,'</p>';
                    }

                if($pages >= 1 && $pages <= $pages){
                    for($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++){
                        echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></strong> ' :  '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
                    }

                }
```

This the whole content of my code.
I'm making a search box but every time I enter in empty value I got the error and it displays all the records in my database.

Comment: This code is not where your error is happening.  Post more code.

Comment: this code is correct? can you please send the hole code ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just before the query. You need to ensure the variables exist before you use them.

```
[..]
            if ( isset( $searchw ) && isset( $searchq ) ) {
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sheet1 WHERE lname like '%$searchq%' AND fname like '%$searchw%' LIMIT $start, $per_page");
                    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        echo '<p>', $query_row['fname'] . ' ' . $query_row['lname'] ,'</p>';
                    }
            } else {
                 // variables not set...
                 echo "You performed an empty search.";
            }
[..]
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your idea, I will revise my code now - Set Sail Media